# iOS simply dropdown number selector

Tags: ios

I want a every simple dropdown number selector. I.e. have a range of values from 1 - 10. I want it to be compact like a html page would have. Does anything like this exist or do I have to use UIPickerView?

Comment: `UIPickerView` is only option.

Comment: it's horrendously ugly

Comment: Check `KDropDownMultipleSelection` on GitHub

Comment: @KexAri, you may need to accept what Apple thinks about the Interface of iOS, and you may need to respect your users as well because they expect those kinda controls on a UI – but you are free to do more intuitive controls for doing a specific task, but most of the cases these kinda tries end creating something less useless interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nidropdown

Or using with UIPickerView http://www.ryadel.com/en/downpicker-drop-down-list-combobox-for-ios-in-objective-c/